# MVC4 form validation - custom html messages howto?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

Ok guys, I'm struggling with this one.  I have found examples of vanilla form validation (highlight text box and display red text) in MVC4 and in jQuery using the validation plugin, however, they aren't too helpful when trying to do custom styled stuff.

Example, in an ajax form, when a user submits the form, and a parameter is wrong (in the controller after a post), I'd like to show a custom HTML element on the page- a div with text inside of it, that way I can style the div appropriately for my site.

In my quest to find an answer, I discovered ModelState.AddModelError() - this is great if you just want to display text, not a div, as it just adds a  to the page that I could style, however I need more than just a  to show up.

Does anyone have any good demo/examples of this?

I've added a simple example image, if a password is incorrect, I'd like to display the message to the right (a combination of html and css):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your View you can use ValidationMessageFor and add some class. To use this, make sure you specified the right Property name with AddModelError, or that you used metadata validation in the class in combinaison with `TryValidateModel()`

**View code:**

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PropertyX, null, new { @class ="error-propertyx" })
```

**Validation model code:**

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredField", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationRes))]
public string PropertyX { get; set; }
```

Or you can use an approach like the following if you want something more involved

http://buildstarted.com/2010/09/14/creating-your-own-modelmetadataprovider-to-handle-custom-attributes/

Creating a separate extension method is also an option, note that this is not the most optimal code, but it'll do what you want :)

```
public static MvcHtmlString CustomValidatioMessageFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper obj, Expression<Func<TModel,TProperty>> expression){

    string html = (string)obj.ValidationMessageFor(expression);
    html = "<div>" + html + "</div>";
    return new MvcHtmlString(html);
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing, @Html.ValidationMessageFor(), however, it only adds a span to the html page, I'd like to add my own custom div, thats where I'm having trouble.  I think there is a way to do this via jquery but I haven't found any examples.

Comment: @SteveStokes for sure you can do anything client side, if you want server side processing, you'll need to look at the link I provided, or maybe you can try @Html.Raw() where the null is in my example.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I ended up giving up and using an image with ValidationMessageFor.  I wish there was a better solution.

Comment: I'm not so sure about that extension method.  If I'm not mistaken this will just emit the outer html shell, but will not actually give you the same behavior as the ValidationMessage.

Answer (score -1):

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
    public sealed class CCompareAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
    {
        private const string _defaultErrorMessage = "Confirm password should match with password field.";
        private readonly int _minCharacters = Membership.Provider.MinRequiredPasswordLength;
        private string name;

        public CCompareAttribute(string compare)
            : base(_defaultErrorMessage)
        {
            name = compare;
        }

        public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
        {
            return String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, ErrorMessageString);
        }

        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            string valueAsString = value as string;
            return (valueAsString != null);
        }

        public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
        {
            return new[]{
            new ModelClientValidationEqualToRule(FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName()),name)
        };
        }
    }




    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public class TypeErrorMessageAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
        public string ErrorMessageResourceName { get; set; }
        public Type ErrorMessageResourceType { get; set; }

        public TypeErrorMessageAttribute()
        {
        }

        public string GetErrorMessage()
        {
            PropertyInfo prop = ErrorMessageResourceType.GetProperty(ErrorMessageResourceName);
            return prop.GetValue(null, null).ToString();
        }
    }
```